# Find the number of possible pairs of the number of days required by Ramu and Krishna respectively to complete the work independently

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

If Ramu and Krishna work on alternate days to complete a work, then the work gets completed in exactly 24 days. If R and K denote the number of days required by Ramu and Krishna respectively to complete the work independently, then how many ordered pairs of integral values of R and K are possible?

If Ramu and Krishna work independently then they are doing work for 12 days. How to find the integral pairs. I am stuck and I think it is a really tricky one

Comment: Seems like you are looking for the number of ways to write $24 = R+K$ as an ordered sum of two positive integers, where $R,K \leq 12$.

Comment: I did not understand this one @LetGBeTheGraph

Answer (score 1):

In one day, Ramu can do $\large{\frac{1}{R}}$ of the job.

In one day, Krishna can do $\large{\frac{1}{K}}$ of the job.

In $2$ days, working on alternate days, they can do $\large{\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{K}}$ of the job.

In $24$ days, working on alternate days, they can do $12\left(\large{\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{K}}\right)$ of the job.

Given that it take $24$ days (assumed exact) for them to complete the job,
we get
\begin{align*}
&12\left(\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{K}\right)=1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&12(R+K)=RK\\[4pt]
\implies\;&RK-12R-12K=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(R-12)(K-12)=12^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
So for every pair $(a,b)$ of positive integers such that $ab=12^2$, we get a pair $(R,K)=(12+a,12+b)$.

It remains to count the number of positive integer factors of $12^2$.

Since $12^2 = (2^4)(3^2)$, it follows that $12^2$ has $(4+1)(2+1)=15$ positive integer factors, hence there are $15$ valid $(R,K)$ pairs.